# More Restful Way To Upload Files

Tags: rest

I am trying to decide which way is more restful. Either:

```
POST /v1/files/uploads
```

With file multipart data in the body of the request.

Or should I specify the resource by filename when uploading?

```
POST /v1/files/uploads/foo.jpg
```

Which one do you prefer? I am leaning towards the second one but not sure what is the best practice in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the first one, I mean:

```
POST /files/uploads/
```

(`v1` is removed deliberately, versioning should be done via headers) or even:

```
POST /files/
```

should be good enough to handle the file upload.

`multipart/form-data` content type should be used and file content along with file name should be passed in the form. Resource name can be considered as an *ID* and when creating a new resource you don't know the *ID* (in RESTful style) since it's generated by the server.